# python pandas: pivoting columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like:

```
country | name  | medals_won | year
-----------------------------------
US      | sarah |      1     | 2010
US      | sarah |      2     | 2011
US      | sarah |      5     | 2015
US      | alice |      3     | 2010
US      | alice |      4     | 2012
US      | alice |      1     | 2015
AU      | jones |      2     | 2013
AU      | jones |      8     | 2015
```

I want it like:

```
country | name  | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015
---------------------------------------------------------
US      | sarah | 1    | 2    | 0    | 0    | 0    | 5
US      | alice | 3    | 0    | 4    | 0    | 0    | 1
AU      | jones | 0    | 0    | 0    | 2    | 0    | 8
```

I've tinkered with `df.apply`, or even brute-force iteration, but you can probably guess that the tricky part is that these row values aren't strictly sequential, so this isn't a simple transpose operation (nobody won any medals in 2014, for e.g., but I want the resulting table to show that in a column full of zeros).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['country','name','year'])['medals_won'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
year           2010  2011  2012  2013  2015
country name                               
AU      jones     0     0     0     2     8
US      alice     3     0     4     0     1
        sarah     1     2     0     0     5
```

If duplicates need aggregation like `mean`, `sum`... with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `aggregate function` + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
  country   name  medals_won  year
0      US  sarah           1  2010 <-same US  sarah 2010, different 1
1      US  sarah           4  2010 <-same US  sarah 2010, different 4
2      US  sarah           2  2011
3      US  sarah           5  2015
4      US  alice           3  2010
5      US  alice           4  2012
6      US  alice           1  2015
7      AU  jones           2  2013
8      AU  jones           8  2015

df = df.pivot_table(index=['country','name'], 
                    columns='year', 
                    values='medals_won', 
                    fill_value=0, 
                    aggfunc='mean')
print (df)
year           2010  2011  2012  2013  2015
country name                               
AU      jones   0.0     0     0     2     8
US      alice   3.0     0     4     0     1
        sarah   2.5     2     0     0     5 <- (1+4)/2 = 2.5
```

Alternatively:

```
df = df.groupby(['country','name','year'])['medals_won'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
year           2010  2011  2012  2013  2015
country name                               
AU      jones   0.0   0.0   0.0   2.0   8.0
US      alice   3.0   0.0   4.0   0.0   1.0
        sarah   2.5   2.0   0.0   0.0   5.0
```

Last:

```
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  country   name  2010  2011  2012  2013  2015
0      AU  jones     0     0     0     2     8
1      US  alice     3     0     4     0     1
2      US  sarah     1     2     0     0     5
```

Comment: Now that is just greedy taking all the answers. :-)

Comment: Yes, but always I think is necessary explain difference between solutions - if automatically use always `pivot_table` and no idea about aggreagtion, then all works nice but if data changed people are surprised whats going on. But If know there is aggreagtion, no problem. ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **pivot_table()** function of **pandas** and fill **nan** values with **zero** using  **pd.fillna(0)**

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'country' : pd.Series(['US', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'US', 'AU', 'AU']),
        'name' : pd.Series(['sarah', 'sarah','sarah','alice','alice','alice','jones','jones']),
        'medals_won' : pd.Series([1,2,5,3,4,1,2,8]),
        'year': pd.Series([2010,2011,2015,2010,2012,2015,2013,2015])    
        })
    pd.pivot_table(df, index=['country','name'], columns='year', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th4Kz.png)